# gradle build stuck at exectuting :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug

Tags: flutter, gradle

programmers of StackOverflow!

my Gradle build is stuck at `:app:compileFlutterBuildDebug`

the command I ran `.\gradlew clean build`

[image: terminal output]

I am trying to run `.\gradlew clean build` because my `flutter run -v` was just stuck at building Gradle, so I thought of running `.\gradlew clean build` manually, but it's still stuck =(

let me know if y'all need more information, such as log files? I'll be happy to add them

EDIT: it has been 20 minutes, it's still the same ='(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone who's facing this issue,

Run `flutter pub cache repair` , this fixed my issue